# C++ schedule task with a non administrator account

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, scheduling

I have been looking for a solution for 2 weeks now. I have seen solutions like schtasks, timeouts, timer loops, xml-triggering, etc.

However, I can't get it working on my C++ application compiling with MinGW GCC-compiler. What I'm looking for is a C++ solution to schedule a task e.g. notepad.exe. I also have to be able to adjust the task, for instance by changing the trigger-time. ***(The biggest problem is that my application that is going to schedule will be ran by non-administrators!)***

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to get it to work. I have also tried [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446861(v=vs.85).aspx), but it won't compile because I'm missing `comdef.h`, `wincred.h` and `taskschd.h`? Besides that, I also can't use pragma statements with my GCC-compiler...

So, if anyone has a solution for my problem, please speak :)

Comment: You should have these files I have them in both my MinGW and MSVC installation.  Note that the Community edition of MSVC 2017 is completely free and full featured.

Comment: @RichardCritten, apparently I have not. When I get them from the internet it still doesn't work, but I'm not sure whether thsse are the appropriate files?

Comment: @RichardCritten, first of all i'm  a hobbyist so I will try to answer your questions as accurate as possible. The compiler package is Use is the CodeBlocks MinGW GCC-compiler on a Windows 10 platform (64-bit). Is this an appropriate answer on your question?